# Django, designing a model that is partially linked with another model

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I am developing a functionality to limit Blog visibility to a given list of users(Blog viewers). I want to use email address to add a viewer so if a user does not already exist with this email address then an invite is sent to the user to create an account.

So in BlogViewer I have email addresses some of which exist in my User model and some don't. How do I link my BlogViewer model to my Users model? Should I split my BlogViewer into two models, one with existing users so I can use ForeignKey and the other with non-existing users?

```
def Blog(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField()
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField(BlogViewer)

def BlogViewerr(models.Model):
    email= models.EmailField()


#Part of my User model
def User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    username = models.CharField()
    ...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using nullable foreign key and designing model like this:

```
def Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    ...
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField(UserModel, through='BlogViewer')

def BlogViewer(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, null=True)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
```

If a user with given email address exists, then the user field is updated otherwise it is left null. If user does not exist I can still use email address to send an email to the user with invitation to join.